# How to package large data in a Qt Project?

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, assets, packaging

I'm working on a Qt Project that includes a large data set (70Mb+).

The data will be used by a library that accesses them using the data's path.

I know that I can use resources normally, but since they are in memory objects, I can't use them with the library.

So my question is, how can I package a file or a folder so that it is available at installation/runtime for anyone to access?

Comment: Why not to archive your data and unpack it on each time you need it into temporary directory ? So your distribution will always have archived data and you'll unpack it only when you need it.

Comment: I'm currently packing it as resources and copying it at runtime, but both affect the ux after installation.

I would love to consider other options before resorting to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending more time with Qt and C++ development in general is that you don't need Qt at all for this functionality.

What you need is to modify your building process to ship the files you need with the binaries once the building is finished.

The great news is that this is super simple with cmake.

Just copy whatever files you want to have available at runtime to the output directory after building the cmake code that does that:

```
 add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT} POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                       ${RES_DIR} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT}>/RES/)
```

where PROJECT is the name of the target.

RES_DIR: full path to resources directory.

Answer (score 2):

The resources are available in the process's memory, so any library that is used within your process has access to them as well. Simply use the `QResource` class to find out the address and size of the resource, and pass it to the library.

If the library can't take a pointer and a size to the data, but insists on a file, you can use `QResource`, `QTemporaryFile` and `QFile::copy` to dump the data from your executable into a temporary file so that the library has something to work with.

The library should have two ways of accepting data:

1. In-process data: address + size. E.g.

   ```
   setData(void * address, int size);
   ```
2. Out-of-process data: file path + offset + size.

   ```
   setData(const char * filePath, void * offset = 0, int size = -1);
   // size = -1 uses the entire file
   ```

This would allow the library to:

1. Use binary resources that are available in the process's memory, whether they come from `QResource`, or WINAPI resources, or held in temporary buffers after being downloaded from the network, etc.
2. Use binary resources that are available in files, including Qt and Windows resources that are available at an offset into the executable file itself.

Comment: as I stated the library needs a path, it handles accessing the files on its own. so that wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Mr.Me Fix the library, then. At the very minimum, the library should accept a path *and* an offset into the file. You can then point the library to the executable itself, and provide an offset at which the resource resides there. If not, you'll have to use `QResource`, `QTemporaryFile`, and `QFile::copy` to dump the resource to a temporary file.

Comment: can't just fix the library, I'll raise the issue for the library team, but Qt should support packaging assets across all platforms.